# request случайным образом ломается с ошибкой "JSON Decoder error"

Tags: python, json, requests

Написал код с реквестом, который получает данные в формате JSON

```
r = requests.get('ССЫЛКА НА САЙТ', headers=headers, timeout=25)
r = r.json()
```

И примерно раз в час, в рандомный момент выходит ошибка:

> requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError

И сервер присылает ответ Response 404, при повторной проверке через секунду даже, уже все нормально.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Да в чём угодно. Вы логируйте что приходит в статусе и в тексте, может там написано, что сервер на обслуживании или ещё что-то, всё, что угодно. И проверяйте статус. Если статус ОК, тогда берите `json` от ответа, а иначе не берите.

Answer (score 0):

Перед тем чтобы что-то делать надо как минимум проверять что запрос отработал корректно

```
r = requests.get('ССЫЛКА НА САЙТ', headers=headers, timeout=25)
if r.status_code==200:
        response = r.json()
```

Ну и далее, если возможен возврат чего-то отличного от json, преобразовывать внутри [try/except](https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/isklyucheniya-v-python-konstrukciya-try-except-dlya-obrabotki-isklyuchenij.html)